# Align input boxes using css

Tags: css, html, alignment

I know this question has been asked before, but I can't find anything that helps me. I have used 'table' and 'inline' to align my input boxes to no avail. I understand that I am using these wrong, I am just not sure where.

HTML5 code

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html lang = 'en'>
<head>
    <meta charset = 'UTF-8'/>
    <script src = 'ABS.js'></script>
    <link rel = 'stylesheet' href = 'ABS.css'/>
    <h1> Adventure Booking System </h1>
    <h3> Student Name: Kyle Sharp - ID: 101604364 </h3>
</head>
<body>
<div class = 'alignline'>
    <p class = 'left'> Enter Customer Name </p><input type = 'text' id = 'custname'/> <br />
    <p class = 'left'> Enter Adventure Code </p><input type = 'text' id = 'advcode'/> <br />
    <p class = 'left'> Enter Lunch Code </p><input type = 'text' id = 'lunchcode'/> <br />
    <p class = 'left'> Enter No. of people </p><input type = 'text' id = 'nopeople'/> <br />
    <p class = 'left'> Enter Seller ID </p><input type = 'text' id = 'sellerid'/> <br />
</div>

    <button type = 'button' onclick = 'displayAdvOptions()'> Show Adventure Options and Prices </button> <br />
    <button type = 'button' onclick = 'displayLunchOptions()'> Show Lunch Options and Prices </button> <br />
    <button type = 'button' onclick 'validateAndCalc()'> Validate data and calculate total </button> <br />
    <p id = 'msg1'></p>
    <p id = 'msg2'></p>
    <p id = 'msg3'></p>
    <p id = 'msg3'></p>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS code

```
body {
    background-color: Yellow;
    display: table;
}

h1 {
    color: blue;
    font-family: Impact, Charcoal, sans-serif;
}

h3 {
    font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
}

.left {
    color: purple;
    font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.alignline p{
    display: inline;
}

button {
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

Forgive the horrid colour pallete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I change you code a bit to make it align properly

```css
body {
    background-color: Yellow;
    display: table;
}

h1 {
    color: blue;
    font-family: Impact, Charcoal, sans-serif;
}

h3 {
    font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
}

.left {
    color: purple;
    font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.alignline p{
    display: inline;
}

button {
    margin-top: 10px;
}
.clear-float p{
  float: left;
  margin: 4px 0;
  padding-right: 15px;
}
.clear-float input{
  float: right; 
  margin: 4px 0;
}
.clear-float{
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class = 'alignline'>
    <div class="clear-float">
      <p class = 'left'> Enter Customer Name </p>
      <input type = 'text' id = ''/>
    </div>
    
    <div class="clear-float">
      <p class = 'left'> Enter Adventure  code </p>
      <input type = 'text' id = ''/>
    </div>
    
    <div class="clear-float">
      <p class = 'left'> Enter Lunch Code </p>
      <input type = 'text' id = ''/>
    </div>
    
    <div class="clear-float">
      <p class = 'left'> Enter Customer Name </p>
      <input type = 'text' id = ''/>
    </div>
</div>

<button type = 'button' onclick = 'displayAdvOptions()'> Show Adventure Options and Prices </button> <br />
    <button type = 'button' onclick = 'displayLunchOptions()'> Show Lunch Options and Prices </button> <br />
    <button type = 'button' onclick 'validateAndCalc()'> Validate data and calculate total </button> <br />
    <p id = 'msg1'></p>
    <p id = 'msg2'></p>
    <p id = 'msg3'></p>
    <p id = 'msg3'></p>
```

Comment: What does the 0 in 'margin: 4px 0' mean? Adn what does clear do?

Comment: 0 in margin means im making left and right margin as 0

Comment: Thanks, one last thing. When I run the whole code, so including my buttons, the button closest to the input boxes and paragraphs is moved to the right. Where as the bottom 2 remain fine. How can I fix this

Comment: and i used css float to align items properly left and right, so whenever we use float we have to clear float at parent so clear both, I strongly suggest you to learn more about html,css and js if u want to do something in this field

Comment: @Ghrafkly checkout my updated code, it looks fine to me, if above answer works for u u can marked it as accepted

Comment: Got it, I had made some changes to your padding and margins.That's why it broke